# django add subdomain based on model

Tags: python, django, subdomain

I want to have subdomain in my django project based on my model. Here is an example:

```
class blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

I would like for example to create a blog called django and access it on the url

> django.localhost:8000/

I have seen [django subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but I don't know if it's fit for me and how to configure it(ROOT_URLCONF, SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS, urls etc...).

I'm open to any librairie if needed.
I use python 3.4 and django 1.8

Comment: I don't even know where to start from. Your subdomains need to be resolved somewhere, either your local `/etc/hosts` or some nameserver. Do you want this to be accessible from outside of your LAN?

Comment: it will be more logic to base your subdomain on your different project.

Comment: This is just a project I will use on my computer so no need to be access from outside. I need to base my subdomain on my model because users can add blog

Comment: You mean users will need to be physically working on your computer, or that you'll be serving the project from your computer?

Comment: it's a school project, so it will not be online. I need to create users who can create blog and see it this way